# Whitespace doesnt want to be cleaned

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I have white space in my data that doesnt seem to want to be cleaned. If i use is.na on column it returns FALSE for blank cells in data. Formulas use sofar havent worked for me. I am fairly new to R and only no a xcouple of ways to clean blanks

I have tried to use stringr to clean and replace with NA

```
 data_wcci01 <- data_wcci01 %>% mutate(Data7 = str_replace_all(Data7,"[[:blank:]]","NA"))
 data_wcci01 <- data_wcci01 %>% mutate(Data7 = str_replace_all(Data7,"[[:space:]]","NA"))
```

I would like all blank cells to have NA

Comment: could you please provide an example of the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `na_if()` from `dplyr`. As @joran notes, `str_squish()` removes excess whitespace.

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

data_wcci01 <- data_wcci01 %>% 
  mutate(Data7 = na_if(str_squish(Data7),""))
```

Comment: Note that we don't really know yet what the OP data contains; this won't work if they are trying to remove empty character values, i.e. `""`. In either case, it might be simpler to just recommend `stringr::str_squish` if they're already using that package.

Comment: @joran that makes sense. I was not familiar with `str_squish()`, thank you for pointing it out. I have updated my answer. I agree we don't know what the data contains, but I figured this was a general enough solution.